# Is it possible to get the length of a ray inside an object with nodes?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Is it possible to get the distance a ray travels inside an object with cycles material nodes?

[image]

Then map it to a 0-1 range to create a map:

[image]

E.g. to adjust the color of a *Glass* node to make it more transparent where there is less volume between the camera and light:

[image]

How can I do this?

---

*The example images above were rendered with the Layer weight node. This only works on spheres.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always the way you ask. Ray length is the distance from previous bounce or refraction.

What might be a bit confusing - you have to apply toning to the inner side (backfacing) of your object, because outside rays return distance from other objects - as ray begins from camera, not from light source.

As far as mapping goes - approaches are different - for instance: http://lesterbanks.com/2012/10/using-blenders-raylength-node-to-create-a-re-usable-custom-absorption-shader/

Comment: I watched that video a while ago, but I never was able to get satisfying results..

Comment: I have been playing around with this technique and also [this one from blender cookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender/lessons/4-creating-coffee-and-cup-shaders/), and I think I have better idea how to use these techniques now. Thanks