# Is it possible to visualize ray length info as a black and white map?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Prompted by my [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3540/599), Is it possible to see the output of a node group like this one: (created from [this tutorial on blender cookie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tcHETob9eQ))

[image: node setup image]

[image: Nod group output]

as a easy to visualize (and quick to render) black and white map like this?:

[image: enter link description here]

Simply connecting the output of the group to an emission shader does not let rays through the object, so the output is white:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connecting the emission shader directly, as you suggested won't work indeed, but how about mix of transparent and emission depending on Geometry->Backfacing? Should work.

Edit:
Works for me:
[image]

Comment: Just tested, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Edited the answer. Like this?

Comment: It still seems transparent though..

Comment: It's not. It does illuminate scene, though. But that can be solved by adding another mix with diffuse for non-camera rays

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.. With [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/61602) node setup I got [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/61604).

Comment: You connected HSV node to backfacing flag instead of ray length. It was intended to map ray length to match desired lightness, not control transparency.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but only with other geometry to bounce rays into it. Could you update the screenshot in your answer to the correct node setup?

Comment: Actually it works without extra geometry, I seem to have found a [bug](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=37256&group_id=9&atid=498).

Comment: "I found a bug... Aaand it's gone" :)
Updated setup. Sorry - didn't notice before :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to connect it to a *Transparent* shader:

[image]

This renders a little bit faster than a Glass shader.

It can also help to go into *local view* (<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>)

However, this does not give a black and white result.

---

If anyone can find a faster method or a way to get a black and white result, please post it :)